# How do I generate animated sprites from a number of component sprite sheets

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I found these great fantasy sprite sheets available under a CC license and want to use them for a 2D game in Unity ([as3gamegears](http://www.as3gamegears.com/assets/assets-pack-12-medieval-fantasy-character-sprites/)).

Can anyone help me understand how I put all the component sprite sheets together to make a full sprite. The weapons and clothing are all in different sheets and I guess I would have to use something like GIMP to put them together but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few nice toolkits for Unity which should easily allow you to stack the sprite sheets on top of each other.

- 2D Toolkit: [Unity Asset Store](http://u3d.as/content/unikron-software-ltd/2d-toolkit/1Wi)
- Sprite Manager (Free): [Unity3D Wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=SpriteManager)
- Sprite Manager 2 ($150): [Unity Asset Store](http://u3d.as/content/ab-software/sprite-manager-2-/1rf)

If you do not want to use a toolkit and you simply want to put all of the components together to create a complete sprite, you can create multiple planes in Unity, and layer each component on top of the last. For example; the main sprite of the character is bottom-most, a gloves layer is above the character sprite and a weapons layer is above the gloves layer.

Comment: Hmm, just noticed you are already familiar with the toolkits available: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14348343/282052

Comment: Thanks for the response - it sounds like I should be able to use Orthello to stack the sprites up. I'll have a look at the documentation.